# Throwing fair dice, what can I say about the following two Random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, independence, dice

Droping 2 times fair dice, Let $X$ be the number of drops that got even number, Let $Y$ be the number of drops got a number that is divided by $3$ what is true from the following?

A. $\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]= 1$ and $X$ , $Y$ are independant

B.$\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]= \frac{2}{3}$ and $X$ , $Y$ are independant

C.$\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]= \frac{2}{3}$ and $X$ , $Y$ are **Not** independant

D.$\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]= 1$ and $X$ , $Y$ are **Not** independant

How should I approach this question? Do I really need to calculate the probability function or there is an efficient way to approach it?

Comment: you wrote "Dropping 2 times fair dice" thus how many dice  you drop?. Observe that "dice" is plural

Comment: We throw the dice, writing the result, than throw the same dice one more time. how should I write it in a more clearly way?

Comment: we throw the DIE, one single die....I already assumed that, look my answer. (Dice means more than one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the expectation is is easy to find out the distribution but it is very immediate...

First observe that

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Even}]=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Div 3}]=\frac{12}{36}=\frac{1}{3}$$

and

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Div 3}|\text{Even}]=\frac{6}{18}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Thus being

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Div 3}|\text{Even}]=\mathbb{P}[\text{Div 3}]$$

These events are independent.

Given this property also $X\perp \!\!\!\!\!\!\perp Y$ and $X^2\perp \!\!\!\!\!\!\perp Y$

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]= \mathbb{E}[X^2]\cdot\mathbb{E}[Y]=\Bigg(\frac{2}{4}+1 \Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{4}{9}+\frac{2}{9}\Bigg)=1$$

Comment: A shortcut to confirming the first part of tommik's answer:  Suppose that one die is red and one die is green.  Then **regardless** of the number that comes up on the red die, there will be (3 out of 6) numbers on the green die such that the sum of the two dice is even and there will be (2 out of 6) numbers on the green die such that the sum of the two dice is divisible by 3.